# Where to get the list of event types?

Tags: javascript, events, meteor

The official [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps) only says:

> The event's type, such as "click", "blur" or "keypress".

For iOS devices the *touchstart* is another event which is working. Where can I get the full list of all possible events? I like for example actually to get the event for the `<select>` event `hasChanged()`. Is this based on another library?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meteor doesn't define the events it supports — it simply creates a cross-browser event listener wrapper. If you wanted to create custom events and trigger them, Meteor would pick them up.

The native input events supported depends on the browser: the [Mozilla Developer Network reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 6):

Th [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps) also says that all the DOM events are also possible in addition to `click`, `focus`, `blur`, etc.

> Other DOM events are available as well, but for the events above,
>   Meteor has taken some care to ensure that they work uniformly in all
>   browsers.

You can see the list of available Javascript events [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOM_event_reference).